# ChannelInboundMessageHandlerAdapter vs. ChannelOutboundMessageHandlerAdapter

Tags: netty

According to Documentation `ChannelInboundMessageHandlerAdapter` should be used for inbound messages and `ChannelOutboundMessageHandlerAdapter` should be used for outbound messages.

If I look at netty example I can see that `ChannelInboundMessageHandlerAdapter` is always used on Client and server even id client sends messages to Server.

Where each of the handler should be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ChannelInboundMessageHandler is used for inbound messages, so received messages. ChannelOutboundMessageHandler us used for outbound message, so "to-be-send" messages. You only need the ChannelOutboundMessagehandler if you need for example transform messages before they are written to the socket.